# Overriding ContextHierarchy and ContextConfiguration from a meta-annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

We have test classes using a meta-annotation:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/web/WEB-INF/spring.xml" }, name = "parent"),
    @ContextConfiguration("/web/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml")
})
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BaseSpringTest {
}
```

But would like to be able to override, or append to elements of the hierarchy from the test class itself, eg:

```
@BaseSpringTest
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/web/WEB-INF/spring-extension.xml" }, name = "parent")
public class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    ...
}
```

This hasn't worked for us so far... is there any mechanism in place to make this happen?  I found https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11038, but I don't think that is quite the fix for this type of situation.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any mechanism in place to make this happen?

No, there is no such mechanism that supports this style of configuration.

Custom *composed annotations* can be used **instead of** the actual annotations, **not in conjunction with** the actual annotations. This is true across the core Spring Framework (with the exception of perhaps `@Profile` and `@Conditional`).

In other words, you can't declare `@ContextConfiguration` and another annotation that is meta-annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` (e.g., your `@BaseSpringTest`) on the same class. If you do, you'll find that Spring only finds one of those declarations.

However, if you introduce a base class you can achieve your goal (albeit with the requirement to extend that base class):

```
@BaseSpringTest
public abstract class AbstractBaseTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    // ...
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/web/WEB-INF/spring-extension.xml" }, name = "parent")
public class MyTest extends AbstractBaseTests {
    // ...
}
```

Of course, if you're going the 'base class' route, the custom composed annotation is perhaps not as useful to you.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by overriding the [TestContextBootstrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextBootstrapper.html) and supplying an updated [MergedContextConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/MergedContextConfiguration.html) that copies the initial configuration and adds the extra locations from the annotation.

Here is a sample:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/web/WEB-INF/spring.xml" }, name = "parent"),
        @ContextConfiguration("/web/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml")
})
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@BootstrapWith(BaseSpringTest.BaseSpringTestBootstrapper.class)
public @interface BaseSpringTest {
    class BaseSpringTestBootstrapper extends DefaultTestContextBootstrapper {
        @Override
        public TestContext buildTestContext() {
            MergedContextConfiguration config = buildMergedContextConfiguration();

            Set<String> locations = new HashSet<>();
            Collections.addAll(locations, config.getLocations());

            locations.add("/web/WEB-INF/spring.xml");
            locations.add("/web/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml");

            MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig = new MergedContextConfiguration(
                    config.getTestClass(), locations.toArray(new String[0]), config.getClasses(),
                    config.getContextInitializerClasses(), config.getActiveProfiles(), config.getPropertySourceLocations(),
                    config.getPropertySourceProperties(), config.getContextCustomizers(),
                    config.getContextLoader(), getCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(), config.getParent()

            );
            
            return new DefaultTestContext(getBootstrapContext().getTestClass(), mergedConfig, getCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate());
        }
    }
}
```

It might be necessary to construct the configuration differently for @ContextHierarchy, but it should be possible with modifications to the above example.